# Should "ohmmeter" be stressed on the first or second syllables, or both?

Tags: pronunciation, stress, syllables

**Question:**

Which syllable or syllables are stressed in the word *ohmmeter*?

**Context:**

I tried to say the word *ohmmeter* out loud today and realized I am unsure of the correct pronunciation. The double *m* is confusing to me.

From some research on various *‑meter* types, some seem to split the words, whereas others pronounce it in a "run-on" format (for lack of a better description). Like *multimeter* is usually said as *múlti míter" with stresses on the first and third syllables, but *altimeter* is usually said with different stress pattern like *all tímiter*, stressing only the second syllable.

Would it be *óhm méter* with two stresses or *óhm iter* with just one, or something else?

**References:**

For reference in case you are unfamiliar with this device: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohmmeter

And also here is a list of measuring devices so you can see what I mean by the various "*X-meter*" type words: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_measuring_devices

Comment: What did dictionaries say?

Comment: At least one of them says ʹəʋm͵mi:tə (as 2 separate words).

Comment: All the (AmE) dictionaries have pronunciations like /'ow(m) 'mi: tr/. Which is to say " 'owe 'mee tur", stress on the first and second syllable, with an optional long 'm' (whatever that is) or even separation between the first and second syllable. It is written as a single word, but it sounds closer to two words. It is definitely not /'a mi tr/ (even though that is a legitimate possibility.

Comment: One thing to be wary of is allowing the pronunciation to drift towards "ah-meter", which can easily be taken to be "ammeter" (amp-meter), a different kind of meter.

Comment: @Alex_ander I think you´ll probably find that the gap you´re seeing there is just caused by the secondary stress symbol. (If it was two different words pronunciation-wise there wouldn´t be any secondary stress!)

Answer (score 3):

In my electrical engineering courses in college (Southern United States), I always heard long O, both Ms, primary stress on first syllable, secondary stress on second syllable: OHM-mee-ter.  There are two Ms, but the mouth does not open between them. Sort of like Ohmmmmmeeter.

I've listened to both the British and American pronunciations at [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/ohmmeter), and the pronunciation I've heard is somewhere in between those two.

Somewhat like the pronunciation at [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ohmmeter), but with more M on the first syllable.

The closest I've found is the first one at [dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/ohmmeter).

I have not heard OHM-ee-ter, which in my mouth requires a glottal stop before the second syllable, or OH-mee-ter, because I'm definitely hearing and saying an M in the first syllable.

Answer (score 1):

I've always heard `OHM eeter`.

Source: West coast US (California) native English speaker.